# TypeScript not letting me implement interface for argument when mapping over array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, object, interface

I am trying to to map over an array of objects to create a new list item component for each object, in the component I then use some of the key/value pairs to display information if there is any, however, when I try to implement the interface in the argument in the JavaScript map method, I get this TypeScript error:

interface IMovieDBData Argument of type '(movie: IMovieDBData, index: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => Element'. Types of parameters 'movie' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IMovieDBData'.ts(2345)

I cannot figure out how to fix it, here is my code:

```
interface IMovieDBData {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  genre_ids: Array<number>;
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number
}
```

This is the data for the interface:
[image: data for IMovieDBData interface]

Bold is where the map method that is giving me the error is:

```
        {(view === 'carousel' && movieList.length > 0 && showListing === true) &&
          <Carousel
            navButtonsAlwaysVisible={true}
            index={activeChild}
            autoPlay={false}
            timeout={300}
            animation={'slide'}
            next={(next: number) => {
              (next === 2 && page === 1) && setCarouselEdgeCaseBoolean(true);
              (next === 0 && carouselEdgeCaseBoolean) && handlePageChange('click', page + 1);
            }}
            prev={(prev: number) => {
              (prev === movieList.length - 1 && page === 1) && setCarouselEdgeCaseBoolean(false);
              (prev === movieList.length - 1 && page !== 1) && handlePageChange('click', page - 1);
            }}
          >
          {
            **movieList.map((movie: IMovieDBData, index: number) => <CarouselItem key={index} movie={movie}** />)
          }
          </Carousel>
        }
```

This is the component I am trying to create every time it maps:

```
interface IMovieListItemProps {
  movie: IMovieDBData;
}

// Component for listing movies in the carousel view
const CarouselItem = (props: IMovieListItemProps) => {

  const MOVIE_POSTER_API_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
  const [openMovieDbData, setOpenMovieDbData] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  useEffect((): void => {
    axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${props.movie.title}&y=${props.movie.release_date && props.movie.release_date.substr(0, 4)}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_MOVIE_API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => {
      setOpenMovieDbData(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log('OpenMovieDB HTTP GET Request Error response:', error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Paper style={{padding: "30px"}} elevation={50}>
      <h2>{props.movie.title}</h2>
      <p>{props.movie.overview}</p>
      <div>Release Date: {props.movie.release_date ? props.movie.release_date : 'N/A'} </div>
      <div>{openMovieDbData['Ratings'] ? openMovieDbData['Ratings'].map((rating: {Source: string, Value: string}, index: number) => (<div key={index}>{rating.Source}: {rating.Value}</div>)): 'No Reviews '}</div>
      <div>Runtime: {openMovieDbData['Runtime'] ? openMovieDbData['Runtime'] : 'N/A'}</div>
      <div>{openMovieDbData['Director'] ? `Directed by: ${openMovieDbData['Director']}` : 'Director not listed. '}</div>
      <div>{openMovieDbData['Actors'] ? `Actors: ${openMovieDbData['Actors']}` : 'Actors not listed. '}</div>
      <div>Rated: {openMovieDbData['Rated'] ? openMovieDbData['Rated'] : 'N/A'}</div>
      <img alt={'Poster for ' + props.movie.title} src={MOVIE_POSTER_API_URL + props.movie.backdrop_path} />
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

It may be worth mentioning that this was all working fine when I had set the types to any but of course that is not why we use TypeScript.

Comment: Please consider turning this code to a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate what you're seeing.  Right now it looks like TS thinks `movieList` is an array of strings and not an array of your objects.  Why?  Not sure, I don't have enough information to reproduce.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks man, that was the thing, I had set the type of the state to useState< Array<string>>([]) not useState<Array<IMovieDBData>>([]), didn't think about my error being there

Comment: @jcalz Make your second sentance an answer so I can credit you